# Bootstrap 4 - input-btn-padding y and x variable overrides not customising bootstrap.css file

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, visual-studio-2017

ASP.NET project, using the NuGet package bootstrap.sass, version 4.3.1. Using Visual Studio 2017 with the extension Web Compiler to compile the Sass.

In a custom.scss file, I'm overriding many bootstrap variables that work correctly.

When trying to override the variables $input-btn-padding-y and $input-btn-padding-x they do not affect the padding values on the form-control or btn classes in the compiled bootstrap.css file. Other customisations are applied correctly.

Based on the _variables.scss file that ships with bootstrap 4, it looks like customising the input-btn-padding vairables should affect both since their values are derived from the base variables.

When I customise the $input-padding-y, $input-padding-x variables, it customises correctly and updates the form-control class. Same for $btn-padding-y and $btn-padding-x.

Is there anything wrong with customising the base-level $input-btn-padding-y/$input-btn-padding-x variables or am I required to customise the higher level values?

I've tried compiling the Sass with the Web Compiler extension and a custom, basic, gulpfile that achieved the same result. I've also started a fresh project, updated to the same version of bootstrap 4 and ended up in the same place.

The _variables.scss looks like overriding the base variable should work:

```
$input-btn-padding-y:         .375rem !default;
$input-btn-padding-x:         .75rem !default;
...
$btn-padding-y:               $input-btn-padding-y !default;
$btn-padding-x:               $input-btn-padding-x !default;
...
$input-padding-y:                       $input-btn-padding-y !default;
$input-padding-x:                       $input-btn-padding-x !default;
```

The relevant custom.scss overrides:

```
$input-btn-padding-y: 0.75rem;
$input-btn-padding-x: 1rem;
```

Resulting padding for form-control in bootstrap.css:

```
.formcontrol {
    ...
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    ...
}
```

Same for btn:

```
.btn {
    ...
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not creating your own variables for $input-btn-padding-y / x and apply them to the elements you want to override ?

Sorry perhaps I didn't get it what you explained. I don't understand if something is wrong here or if you're asking if something is wrong here haha.

Comment: The thinking is that overriding $input-btn-padding-y/x should effect the variables that are based on them e.g. the btn/input but in reality the change seems totally ignored.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but this is a proper way to overwrite bootstrap sass.

```
// Variables
$primary:       #8a2387;

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": $primary,
);

$input-btn-padding-x: 1rem;

// Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// My Styles goes here


// Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
```